# How to create an object in a cube in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cube in Unity3D. I know the vectors of its 8 vertices. It is rotated and scaled in 3D around all axes. How can I instantiate an object at run time inside that cube at a random position?

Comment: @Heisenbug: I had already posted a comment there, if you didn't see, and used it for rescue and came to a new issue. So after how much minimum time should I post new questions, if any?

Comment: my comment is related mostly on this question. Don't consider it a critic, but only an advice in order to get better answer on SO. Asking "how do this" is often not the better way to get an answer. A better one way could be "I read the documentation, I tried to do what explained ther and here's the code I produced so far, but I still can't understand what's going wrong".

Comment: @Heisenbug: Technically you seem to be correct

Comment: An answer like I gave is an answer you could give to Temp Id. It's of the same level, explaining the practice he could use to achieve his goal. Since no code and no programming language are given in the question, those details are left out as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the 8 vertices of your cube, it's easy to randomize an object inside of this cube. Consider the random object to have an `x`, `y` and `z` value in the position of the Transform. Both UnityScript and C# provide a nice `Random` class which can easily give you a random number between two values. Use this class three times:

1. Create a random number between the max `x` value and the min `x`
   value of all 8 vertices.
2. Create a random number between the max `y` value and the min `y`
   value of all 8 vertices.
3. Create a random number between the max `z` value and the min `z`
   value of all 8 vertices.

Next, create your gameobject which has to be instantiated in this cube, and use the `x`, `y` and `z` value you've calculated from above three steps. That would randomly create your object in the cube.

Note that if your random object has a certain size, it would technically be possible to generate the object randomly on the edge of the cube, thus letting the random object 'stick out' of the cube. To avoid that, make sure to substract half the size of the object from the max values you enter in the randomize function and to add up half the size of the object from the min values you enter in the randomize function.

EDIT: To get your points when the object is rotated, you can use `cube.transform.localScale / 2`. This will get you the local position of one of the cube's corners. `Vector3.Scale(cube.transform.localScale / 2, new Vector3(1,1,-1))` will get you one of the others (different combinations of 1 and -1 there will get you all eight). Then, to find them in world space, use `cube.transform.TransformPoint()`.

Comment: I think this will work only if the cube is aligned at angles 0,0,0 to the world

Comment: @TempId Why is that? Because of the rotation? I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, I'd probably suggest something like the following.

```
public class Instantiation : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
                cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
                cube.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will create the GameObject cube (or whatever you desire) at the new transform.position. However instead of it's position being a specific Vector3, you have it as a randomly generated Vector3 from a new method. This method will be created to randomise the numbers for x then y and z within specific boundaries. You then just feed it into the new position.

I hope that makes sense, I'm not a fantastic teacher.

Edit: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html this is a good reference for instantiating Prefabs. Your run time instantiated object should be of a prefab.

Comment: Doesn't this create cubes on all positions rather than random locations?

Comment: First of all, this will create many cubes. I need to create an existing object (from a prefab) at runtime inside an existing cube whose vertices are known. And the cube is rotated and scaled on all axes.